# How can I make an element float:right without affecting the vertical alignment?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with some text and a caret symbol made with CSS. I would like the caret to float to the right, to the side of the button. However, when I do this, either with CSS's `float:right` (or with Bootstrap's `pull-right`), the vertical alignment changes, and the caret is at the top of the line of text. Here is my code:

```
<button style="width:150px">
Button Text <span style="float:right" class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Here is what I'm seeing with and without the `float:right`:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the desired effect? That is to say, why are you attempting to float an inline-block element? Can't you just use `position: relative` with some negative margin on the right?

Comment: That's a bit of a hack. This is a question that applies to many other scenarios. I'm looking for a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't float an inline-block element. In order to have the caret of the button displayed further to the right as well as at the same height, try simply setting `position: relative` in conjunction with negative right-hand margins:

```
<button>
  Button Text <span style="position: relative, margin-right: -25px;" class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I've created a BootPly demonstrating this [**here**](http://www.bootply.com/7xRnnXWYGy).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This doesn't work because the buttons in your example are not fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be to nest the caret within the floated element.

```
<span class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></span>
```

Comment: Whoops. This doesn't appear to working in Firefox. The caret drops down to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, because you aren't showing the code for class caret. However, I've created a pen that does work. I borrowed the caret icon from another website so you can see it.

```
.caret:after {
  content:
  url('https://www.nknews.org/pro/wp-content/themes/NKNewsvizzPro/images/caret-icon.png')
}
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/wahhabb/pen/qmKNZL

Comment: Your example works on Codepen, but when I run it in my site, Firefox drops the caret down one line. It does the same thing in my answer.

Comment: ...It might be bootstrap that's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the caret and `position: relative` on the parent button.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

.caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<button style="width:150px">
Button Text <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't use absolute positioning, but I wasn't able to figure one out. Using absolute for now...

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `float: right;` and use this bit of code to vertically align it:

```
.caret {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Doesn't matter how tall the button is, it will always be vertically centered.